# StackTrace Java

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method1().length);
    }

    public static StackTraceElement[] method1() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Не могу понять почему длина 3? как это вообще высчитывается? Это длина массива или длина метода? Что такое 3, это какой-то порядковый номер или количество элементов/строк или еще чего-то?

Comment: 1. main(); 
2. method1(); 
3. getStackTrace().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в том, что сам вызов метода `getStackTrace()` также попадает в stack trace, который в итоге выглядит следующим образом:

1. `Solution#main()`;
2. `Solution#method1()`;
3. `java.lang.Thread#getStackTrace()`.

*P.S. указал в прямом порядке для удобства восприятия, на стеке же это лежит в обратном порядке.*

Comment: Правильно я понял, что у stack trace единственная функция - посчитать сколько методов в классе начиная с самого метода getStackTrace() и до самого начала, т.е. все записи где есть "( )" ?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко, на самом деле, все несколько сложнее: "под капотом" данного метода извлекается dump потоков (посредством вызова native метода `java.lang.Thread#dumpThreads`, т.е. метода исходники которого написаны не на Java, а, скорее всего, прямиком в исходниках JVM), элементами dump отдельно взятого потока потока являются сущности `java.lang.StackTraceElement`, в которых имеется информация о имени метода, класса, загрузившего его ClassLoader'а и прочего, а в вашем случае вы игнорируете все кроме количества stack frame'ов.

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко, причем, в рамках JVM в любой момент времени имеется информация о stack'е каждого из потоков, а стек уже состоит из stack frame'ов (так сказать, элементов, в которых записана информация о методе java-класса, текущей исполняемой инструкции в нем, состоянии переменных в нем и так далее), ведь в том числе за счет этого, в том числе, Garbage Collector и работает:

Comment: 1. останавливает все потоки (кроме своего служебного); 2. получает stack каждого из них; 3. в рамках stack пробегает по stack frame'ам stack'а каждого из потоков, ходя по ссылка на элементы в heap'е, помечая их как используемые;
4. после завершения прохода по всем stack frame, stack'а каждого из потоков удаляет из heap все экземпляры классов, которые на пункте 3 не были помечены как используемые.